# Why is vptr (virtual table pointer) pointing to wrong functions

Tags: c++

I have the following class structure:

```
class CLASS_EXPORT A
{
public:
    virtual        bool foo1();
    virtual        bool foo2();
};

class CLASS_EXPORT B: public A{
public:
    B();
    virtual        bool foo1();
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

These classes are inside one dll. When I look at the virtual pointer of the object 'b', it does not show entry for foo2() function. It shows entry for foo1() and a totally different entry from the different class in another dll.

I am using Visual studio 2015 and using quick watch to view the 'this' pointer. Also, while debugging on a debug build, the control goes to the wrong function. When debugged the assembly code for this, base class constructor is assigning wrong vtable pointer inside this pointer of the base class.

00007FFA6323E6CB  lea         rcx,[A::`vftable' (07FFA63422CB8h)]

If I check the values of at 07FFA63422CB8h, it shows incorrect function pointers

Could you please help in figure out what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: The question is about why some particular tool is giving you information that you don't think is correct. But you don't even say what tool you're asking about.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you concerned with the contents of a vtable?

Comment: This question is the consequence of bothering yourself with internal implementation details while assuming that they will match the wording in your C++ textbook (the textbook whose author did not understand abstractions). Of course, that doesn't make it a bad question :) +1

Comment: _"the control goes to the wrong function"_ But _does it_? ;)

Comment: I am asking this because it is executing the wrong function

Comment: But it isn't. The outcome of your program is still what you have asked the computer for. People think that a C++ program is a sequence of instructions A to B on how to accomplish a task. But it's not. It's an _example_ that you give the computer, _one way_ to accomplish the task, and in this way we tell the computer what the task is. But as long as it can take A and still give you B it'll accomplish that task however it pleases. The realities of life mean that often this closely matches what you wrote in your source code, but _this need not be the case_ and that's important to understand.

Comment: Admittedly this particular example I can imagine being quite confusing but, well, that's what happens when you debug a release build ;)

Comment: (If this is a debug build please indicate that in the question)

Comment: This is indeed a debug build

Comment: Could be any number of things, all resulting in Undefined Behavior. One group of causes includes building with incompatible/different headers or defines, violating ODR, linking of incompatible binaries, using incompatible compiler versions, and/or some other snafu in your build system.

Comment: You might also want to show the code where the call goes wrong (and also double-check/tell us what `CLASS_EXPORT` expands to). As it stands, the compiler would be fully in its rights to optimize your entire code to a single `ret` instruction as no side effects are present.

Comment: That's what DLL Hell looks like from a debugger.  Debug > Windows > Modules can show you where it came from.

Answer (score 5):

This is not uncommon; it's permitted under the "as-if rule". In C++, some things have addresses that are visible at the language level, and other things have addresses only as a matter of implementation. For the first, the general rule is that different things must have different addresses *if* the addresses can be compared. But vtables are not visible at the language level, they only have an address because Visual Studio decided it would be convenient internally. There is nothing that restricts Visual Studio's choice of addresses. The code just has to behave according to the rules of the C++ standard, and that doesn't say anything about debuggers.

Comment: *"You can't write `&A::foo1 == &B::foo1`"*  - But you can. Did you mean to say the result is unspecified?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Right - I managed to overlook that in this example the classes **are** related (by inheritance). `void (A::*)()` and `void (B::*)()` share a common type, which is `void (B::*)()` (somewhat counter-intuitively, but every method of A can be called on a B object).